# Why am I gettingSyntaxError in Spree::UserSessionsController#new when install spree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax-error, spree

I have one old rails app which I reopen nowadays and want to figure out why am I getting this syntax error. I'm convinced that it's have some connections with ruby or rails version

```
gem 'spree', '3.0.0'
gem 'spree_gateway', github: 'spree/spree_gateway', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: '3-0-stable'
gem 'spree_static_content', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_static_content', branch: '3-0-stable'
```

It works until try to login or try to go to admin panel. Everytime got same error:

> SyntaxError in Spree::UserSessionsController#new
>
> MyProjects/vendor/bundle/gems/devise-3.5.10/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:5:
>   syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
>   ..."devise.skip_timeout"] = true } ... ^

sessions_controller.rb

```
class Devise::SessionsController < DeviseController
  prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, only: [:new, :create]
  prepend_before_filter :allow_params_authentication!, only: :create
  prepend_before_filter :verify_signed_out_user, only: :destroy
  prepend_before_filter only: [:create, :destroy] { request.env["devise.skip_timeout"] = true }

  # GET /resource/sign_in
  def new
    self.resource = resource_class.new(sign_in_params)
    clean_up_passwords(resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with(resource, serialize_options(resource))
  end

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_flashing_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end

  # DELETE /resource/sign_out
  def destroy
    signed_out = (Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name))
    set_flash_message :notice, :signed_out if signed_out && is_flashing_format?
    yield if block_given?
    respond_to_on_destroy
  end

  protected

  def sign_in_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:sign_in)
  end

  def serialize_options(resource)
    methods = resource_class.authentication_keys.dup
    methods = methods.keys if methods.is_a?(Hash)
    methods << :password if resource.respond_to?(:password)
    { methods: methods, only: [:password] }
  end

  def auth_options
    { scope: resource_name, recall: "#{controller_path}#new" }
  end

  def translation_scope
    'devise.sessions'
  end

  private

  # Check if there is no signed in user before doing the sign out.
  #
  # If there is no signed in user, it will set the flash message and redirect
  # to the after_sign_out path.
  def verify_signed_out_user
    if all_signed_out?
      set_flash_message :notice, :already_signed_out if is_flashing_format?

      respond_to_on_destroy
    end
  end

  def all_signed_out?
    users = Devise.mappings.keys.map { |s| warden.user(scope: s, run_callbacks: false) }

    users.all?(&:blank?)
  end

  def respond_to_on_destroy
    # We actually need to hardcode this as Rails default responder doesn't
    # support returning empty response on GET request
    respond_to do |format|
      format.all { head :no_content }
      format.any(*navigational_formats) { redirect_to after_sign_out_path_for(resource_name) }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the line #5 is using the old syntax and you're probably using a newer version of ruby.

```
prepend_before_filter only: [:create, :destroy] { request.env["devise.skip_timeout"] = true }
```

It should be (notice the `()`)

```
prepend_before_filter(only: [:create, :destroy]) { request.env["devise.skip_timeout"] = true }
```

devise change it here:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/commit/53957d921b01e993222def6c051901bb4cbe4be9